# No Session.StatusCallback received

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Hello Im trying to use login with facebook.

My problem is that Im not getting the call back.

Here is my code:

```
private void onClickLogin() {

        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }

        // Ask for username and password
        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) this);

        op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        op.setCallback(null);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        // permissions.add("publish_actions");
        permissions.add("user_photos");
        permissions.add("friends_photos");
        permissions.add("read_stream");
        permissions.add("read_insights");
        permissions.add("read_friendlists");
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("publish_actions");

        op.setPermissions(permissions);

        Session session = new Session.Builder(this).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForPublish(op);
    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data2) {

        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(RegisterPage.this, requestCode, resultCode, data2);


    }

rivate class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            Log.i("test", "test");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your callback. You should do something like this

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

.....

I register my callback in the onStart Method

Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);

and I remove it in the onStop Method

Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);

Regards

Michael